# In Android how do you change the background color of a listView without disabling the onClick color?

Tags: android, listview, colors

I have a listView that I need to give a background color to cover up the activity's background image.  I would prefer to do this on a cell basis so that if the listView doesn't reach the bottom of the screen, the background color will show where there are no more list items to display.  Also, I should mention that I have this ListView positioned between to ImageViews using:

```
android:layout_above
```

and

```
android:layout_below
```

So that for smaller screens, the ListView will scroll properly on top of the lower ImageView rather than in front of or behind it.  For larger screens however, I'd like the activity's background image to be visible when there are no more list items to display.

I've been looking around at selectors and that might be what I'm looking for, but from what I'm told the selector's color will display behind the background color for the listView.

This is what I'm trying now.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I'm trying to?

item.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/orange" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/orange" />
  <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/orange" />
</selector>
```

activity_main.xml below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gray_lines" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_header" />

    <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/orange" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:onClick="contactPressed"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/item"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:text="@string/footerText" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainMenuList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="0.1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gray" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="23sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which creates the correct colors as shown below, but the onClick color is not displaying as it should.

[image: activity_main.xml]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is silly.  I had the selector located in the textview instead of the  ListView.  Right things wrong spot.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/footerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:onClick="contactPressed"
        android:text="@string/footerText" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainMenuList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/item"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="0.1dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to set a static color to the listview, add it to the listview element in the xml

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background = "@drawable/somebgdrawable"
/>
```

if you want to add the drawable to a cell

then in your `list_item.xml`

add the background line to the root view of the layout

if your drawable is a selector, then add that
its recognized as @drawable

if you are using list activity

```
getListView().setBackground(Drawable d)
```

if you do this on a cell basis -> the cells will be covered, but if the list does not reach the bottom of the screen, the activity will be visible behind it (if your listview is an overlay)

or you will get a while screen in the rest of it

Comment: I've tried setting the android:background in the ListView, but in my activity I have a custom header and footer that I need to position my ListView between.  So my ListView has android:layout_above and android:layout_below.  The area underneath the list items (where the list items stop) includes the ListView's background color as well instead of the activity's background color.

Comment: Also I've tried setting the background in my list_item.xml, that gives me the colors I want, but the list_selector.xml won't work while using that.

Comment: add an attribute to the listview drawSelectorOnTop=true

Comment: I did not see a change in behavior when trying drawSelectorOnTop="true"

Comment: can you show me the layout of your listview ? both in image & in xml

Comment: Absolutely.  I just added it to my original post because it is easier to read there.

Comment: Sorry just added an image as well.

Comment: are you using listactivity ? where is the xml layout of your listview ?

Comment: I am not using listactivity.  the xml layout of my listview is in main_activity.xml.  It has a scroll bar for some reason.

Comment: do you have any code in your getView that changes the background of anything ?

Comment: No.  I have tried something with that previously, but have since taken it out.  The only background changing I am doing currently is via xml.